# How do I make Visual Studio 2012 deploy the VSIX to Visual Studio 2010 experimental instance?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I have a Visual Studio addin that is opened with Visual Studio 2012. If I click F5 the addin is deployed to Visual Studio 2012 experimental instance and everything works fine. I want to see how the addin works in Visual Studio 2010 and it's be great if I could just have a VS2010 experimental instance started with the addin registered there.

I changed the manifest so that it reads

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[10.0,12.0]" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" Version="[10.0,12.0]" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" Version="[10.0,12.0]" />
</Installation>
```

and on the "Debug" tab of the project settings I changed the path to point to VS2010 devenv.exe

When I click F5 I get Visual Studio 2010 experimental instance running just fine, but my addin is not initialized - clearly it is not deployed there.

How can I have it deployed in this scenario?

Comment: I don't have a solution to your original problem, but it looks like you use vsixmanifest v2.0 format and it is not supported by VS 2010.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Perhaps that's actually the answer. Can I use the v1 format for Studio 2012 and later?

Comment: Yes, you can use the v1 format for VS 2012+. Just copy the xml code from a VS 2010 extension. (But generally, if you want to support VS 2010, it is better to develop it in VS 2010. Or at least create the initial extension project in VS 2010.)

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Interesting, I tried to convert the manifest to v1 and it doesn't make any difference - Visual Studio 2010 experimental starts without the addin deployed.

Answer (score 2):

When you build an extension, it's deployed into just one experimental hive for a single version of Visual Studio. Generally, it should target the same version you're building with, so if you want to try it in Visual Studio 2010, you should build your extension with Visual Studio 2010. If that doesn't work, you can try a command line build of your project with something like

```
msbuild /p:DeployExtension=true /p:VSSDKTargetPlatformVersion=10.0
```

where the "target platform version" specifies which version you want to target. That normally defaults to the SDK version.

Comment: What seems to work well for me now is to just do one-off command-line builds when testing on other versions of Visual Studio. For example, I have an extension developed with VS 2012 that's supported on 2012, 2013, and 2015. If I need to test a feature in 2013, I change the Project's Run Properties to point to the devenv.exe under the 12.0 directory and then each time I build, I also just run "msbuild MyExtension.sln" from a VS 2013 command prompt.